# Drone template not triggering build

Tags: drone.io

Following is how our`.drone.yml` looks like (and template also listed below) this an example configuration very much how we want in our production. The reason we are using a template is that our staging and production have similar configurations with values different in them(hence circuit template). And we wanted to remove duplication using the template `circuit.yaml`.

But currently, we are unable to do so df I don’t define the `test.yaml`(template) and **have test step imported without template** (and have the circuit template define to avoid the duplicate declaration of staging and production build) the drone build fails with

```
"template converter: template name given not found
```

If I **define the test step as a template**. I see the test step working but on creating the tag I see the following error

```
{"commit":"28ac7ad3a01728bd1e9ec2992fee36fae4b7c117","event":"tag","level":"info","msg":"trigger: skipping build, no matching pipelines","pipeline":"test","ref":"refs/tags/v1.4.0","repo":"meetme2meat/drone-example","time":"2022-01-07T19:16:15+05:30"}
```

```yaml
---
kind: template
load: test.yaml
data:
  commands:
    - echo "machine github.com login $${GITHUB_LOGIN} password $${GITHUB_PASSWORD}" > /root/.netrc
    - chmod 600 /root/.netrc
    - go clean -testcache
    - echo "Running test"
    - go test -race ./...
  

---
kind: template
load: circuit.yaml
data:
  deploy: deploy
  create_tags:
    commands:
      - echo "Deploying version $DRONE_SEMVER"
      - echo -n "$DRONE_SEMVER,latest" > .tags
  backend_image:
    version: ${DRONE_SEMVER}
    tags:
      - '${DRONE_SEMVER}'
      - latest
```

And the template is below

#### test.yaml

```yaml
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: test
steps:
  - name: test
    image: golang:latest
    environment:
      GITHUB_LOGIN:
        from_secret: github_username
      GITHUB_PASSWORD:
        from_secret: github_token
    commands:
      {{range .input.commands }}
      - {{ . }}
      {{end}}
    volumes:
      - name: deps
        path: /go

  - name: build
    image: golang:alpine
    commands:
      - go build -v -o out .
    volumes:
      - name: deps
        path: /go

volumes:
  - name: deps
    temp: {}

trigger:
  branch:
    - main
  event:
    - push
    - pull_request
```

#### circuit.yaml

```yaml
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: {{ .input.deploy }}
steps:
  - name: create-tags
    image: alpine
    commands:
    {{range .input.create_tags.commands }}
    - {{ . }}
    {{end}}

  - name: build
    image: plugins/docker
    environment:
      GITHUB_LOGIN:
        from_secret: github_username
      GITHUB_PASSWORD:
        from_secret: github_token
      VERSION: {{ .input.backend_image.version }}
      SERVICE: circuits
    settings:
      auto_tag: false
      repo: ghcr.io/meetme2meat/drone-ci-example
      registry: ghcr.io
```